# Errors while starting an Meteor application + react (static-html)

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, npm, meteor

I have an application running with the Meteor framework + React. I'm trying to start the app using `npm start` command, but I keeping getting these errors about static-html files. I'm pretty new to meteor, so I've tried to run these commands below:

```
meteor remove static-html
meteor add blaze-html-templates
```

but I'm still getting the same errors...

```
=> Errors prevented startup:                  

   While processing files with static-html (for target web.browser):
   deploy/bundle/programs/web.browser/body.html:1: Expected one of: <body>, <head>, <template>
   deploy/bundle/programs/web.browser/head.html:1: Expected one of: <body>, <head>, <template>
   deploy/bundle/programs/web.browser.legacy/body.html:1: Expected one of: <body>, <head>, <template>
   deploy/bundle/programs/web.browser.legacy/head.html:1: Expected one of: <body>, <head>, <template>

   While processing files with static-html (for target web.browser.legacy):
   deploy/bundle/programs/web.browser/body.html:1: Expected one of: <body>, <head>, <template>
   deploy/bundle/programs/web.browser/head.html:1: Expected one of: <body>, <head>, <template>
   deploy/bundle/programs/web.browser.legacy/body.html:1: Expected one of: <body>, <head>, <template>
   deploy/bundle/programs/web.browser.legacy/head.html:1: Expected one of: <body>, <head>, <template>

=> Your application has errors. Waiting for file change.
```

I appreciate any help

Answer (score 0):

You need `react` and `react-dom` to render react component

```
meteor npm install --save react react-dom
```

You need to remove `blaze` add add `static-html` back. `static-html` used to render init html element then `react` can take over from there.

```
meteor remove blaze-html-templates
meteor add static-html
```

Meteor Guide for React
https://guide.meteor.com/react.html

Comment: I run the scripts above, but I still got the same errors... no changes

Comment: you should restart `meteor` command and ensure you run command in the correct folder